# how to set unique name of each distinct values of a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `testTble` with column `testVal` which is containing duplicate value. I can find the each *unique* value of the column using `DISTINCT(testVal)`. But I want to set a specific name of each *unique* value of the column.

Like:

I run the query in my db and found those distinct value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(testVal) AS web FROM `testTble`
```

Output:

```
web
169.254.15.169
10.0.0.91
192.168.80.47
10
```

Now I want to set a unique name of those values like this:

`169.254.15.169` as `web21`
`10.0.0.91` as `web22`

So how can I set a name like this?

Comment: What if you run out of letters a-z?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: I mean cannot set a unique name of each distinct value. Like if I fount 5 distinct value then name will be like `web21` , `web22` --- `web25`

Comment: @ Yogesh Sharma I edited my question and added some real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select test_val, row_number() over (order by test_val)
from t
group by test_val;
```

In earlier versions, you can use variables:

```
select test_val, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by test_val;
```

In both cases, the "name" is a numeric value, but that seems consistent with what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, the Second one is setting a numeric value of each distinct value. But how can I set `string` type name?  I mean AB1 or AB2

Comment: Change  (rn := rn + 1) to 'AB' + cast ( (rn := rn + 1) as varchar) (had to take the ats out as comments don't like them!)

Comment: `select ServerPort, 'AB' + cast ( (rn := rn + 1) as varchar) from services cross join (select @rn := 0) params group by ServerPort` like this?  But it's showing an error`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= rn + 1) as varchar) from services cross join (select @rn := 0) params group b' at line 1`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you help me to set a string type name?

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman . . . If you need a string:  `cast( (@rn := @rn + 1) as char )`.  Or more simply:  `concat('AB', (@rn := @rn + 1))`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you very much.